# Is there any working sample of ms bot for azure government

Tags: azure-active-directory, botframework, azure-bot-service

I am new to bot framework and working on it (v4) for last couple of weeks and was able to have a working bot with luis and qnamaker integrated with the help of available samples. When I deployed the same bot on Azure Government, it was not working. Then I searched a lot and came across many differences (mainly about the URL and endpoints) between azure public cloud and government.

I followed below links for code changes to make in the bot code. But still the bot is not working.

[How do I create a bot that uses the US Government data center](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-resources-bot-framework-faq?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#channels)

[Last comment by EricDahlvang](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-V3/issues/130)

Interestingly, the default echo bot available in azure government is also not working. When I tried to create it with option to auto create AAD app id and password, I received an error: "Authentication_Unauthorized: Access for application 'GUID' is blocked due to missing permission configuration".

[Screenshot of the error facing with echo bot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S6COn.png)

For above, I am using trial azure government account.

Comment: To clarify; on the echo bot, at what point do you receive that error? when trying to provision/create the bot with AAD appid/password?

Comment: Hi Dana, Thank you for the response. Yes, the error occurs when I try to create Web App Bot resource. I have updated the question with a screenshot.

Comment: I think this might have to do with your permissions in the active directory. Are you an admin in the directory you are using, or just a contributor? (my assumption is admin, but not sure how trial gov works). Are you able to create App Registrations outside of bot creation?

Comment: I had to reach ms support for this issue and as per them there are two instances of the cloud and the application GUID mentioned in error message shown in the screenshot represents Bot Framework. This GUID is incorrectly configured for one cloud instance and this one is where our trial azure gov account is hosted. I am waiting for further response from them about resolution. I appreciate your time and inputs so far on the Issue.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out that for Azure Government there are two lines which must be added to the appsettings.json

```
  "BotEnv": "usgovprd",
  "ChannelService": "https://botframework.azure.us",
```

I was successfully able to publish to MAG from visual studio once I added these two settings.

Answer (score 0):

Finally! its working by upgrading to bot framework v4.9.3 and adding below two lines inside services.AddBot method in ConfigureServices.

```
services.AddBot<ChatBot>(options =>
{
options.ChannelProvider = new ConfigurationChannelProvider(_configuration);
options.AppCredentials = new MicrosoftGovernmentAppCredentials(MSAppId, MSAppPassword);

// rest of the code
});
```